# How to store each row of the csv file to array in php

Tags: php

I have data in csv file as follows.

Mr,Vinay,H S,Application Engineer,vinay.hs@springpeople.com,99005809800,Yes
Mr,Mahammad,Hussain,Application Engineer,vinay.hs@springpeople.com,99005809800,Yes

I want to store each row in each array.explain me how to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the CSV is a file (if not, make the CSV match the `$csv`, which is essentially the file broken down in the separate lines), here is a very simple way:

```
$csv = file('mycsv.csv'); $result = array();
//iterate the lines
foreach ($csv as $line)
  // I'd recommend  more robust "csv-following" method though (fgetcsv maybe)
  $result[] = explode(',',$result); 
//show the results
print_r($result);
```

Though [`fgetcsv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) is probably a safer bet (as others have mentioned) (See the docs).

---

To further extend your comment:

```
//iterate the lines
foreach ($csv as $line)
  // I'd recommend  more robust "csv-following" method though (fgetcsv maybe)
  $result[] = explode(',',$result);
```

can become:

```
//iterate the lines
foreach ($csv as $line)
  // combine the current results with the new results
  $result = array_marge($result,$line);
```

or, if order is important:

```
//iterate the lines
foreach ($csv as $line)
  // add each result on to the end of the result array
  foreach($line as $val)
    // add each value
    $result[] = $val;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply,now $result is a two dimensional array , i want to store each row in csv file to single array.plese explain me to do this

Comment: @Vinay: Depending how you want to do it, you can do a couple of things: `$result[] = explode(',',$result);` can become `$result = array_merge($result,explode(',',$line));` or `foreach (explode(',',$line) as $val) $result[] = $val;`

Comment: @Vinay: Please see the updated answer for further clarification.

Answer (score 1):

I did not understand each row in each array.

use [fgetcsv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) function to read the CSV file php.

An example

```
<?php
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

OR
If you want to store them in an array you could use

```
$data = array();
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while(($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $data[] = $row;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [fgetcsv()](http://php.net/fgetcsv) for that:

```
$data = array();
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while(($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $data[] = $row;
    }
}
```